# Pivoting table with duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a table of survey responses, and the responses by each subject for each question are listed out in rows, not columns.

Here is an example of the table:

[image: Example of the input table]

After searching, I was able to pivot it using this:

```
 SELECT id, question, answer
 MAX (CASE WHEN [question] = 'do you like cheese' THEN [answer] ELSE NULL END) AS [q1],
 MAX (CASE WHEN [question] = 'what type of cheese' THEN [answer] ELSE NULL END) AS [q2]
 MAX (CASE WHEN [question] = 'where do you buy your cheese' THEN [answer] ELSE NULL END) AS [q3]
 FROM CheeseTable
 GROUP BY id
```

However, as you can see from the table in the link above, there are 2 entries with id = 1 that have different answers.

Basically, they are the same person, but they filled the survey twice (i.e., follow-up). When I use GROUP BY it only pivots one of the duplicate ids. Is there a way to also pivot and include the duplicate ids?

This is the output I want to get:

[image: Example of desired output]

Comment: You are aggregating your data so the output is exactly what you are asking it for. Can you post the table structure and sample data? From what you posted it looks like you need some serious normalization.

Comment: Yes, I know the data is **bad**. I do not have the ability to change the database, I just have to get information out of the data. I do not enjoy working with this inferior product. Not one bit. It has been quite a struggle trying to get the higher ups to realize this is not workable. I am just trying to make an omelet out of all these broken eggs swimming in sewage. Thanks for your validation that I am not the only one pulling my hair out. Sorry to vent bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption is that you want the answers for multiple occurances of a survey to stay together.

First, create a query that adds a column for "SurveyID".  "Survey ID" is a code that makes each survey from an "ID" have a unique code (1,2,3 or A,B,C).  Doing that is acutally a different question.

However once you have added this column (even just in a temporary subquery), you can feed it though your pivot, add it to your "group by", then not put it in the "select"

Comment: Thanks, I think I might be able to find a unique Survey ID produced by the vendor that is linked to each unique survey response. Two thumbs up!